# Explanation about Excel workbook opening issue in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I had an issue with Excel workbook opening. After some research I've found a way (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320369) to solve this issue by changing the CultureInfo of the current execution thread.

Does anyone could bring me more information about this issue ? I mean, why this issue is happening? Is there a way to know where the problem is coming from exactly ? (Is this from a specific column or row ? Does it related with some properties within the .xlsx file ?...)

Hope I've been clear.
Thanks.

P.S: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two solutions set your thread's culture information to match what Excel is expecting. The last solution does the reverse, and creates the 'missing' localization file.

The CurrentCulture property tells Excel how to localize the GUI. If you are running a version of Excel that doesn't perfectly 'mesh' with your version of Windows, the localizer cannot figure out what localization files should be used. I suspect that the Excel startup code has some logic that figures this out, but it doesn't get executed when you call Excel via automation, so you essentially have to do it manually (ie, any one of the steps described in the MS article).